# Secure communication between nginx-ingress and .net core container

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, .net-core, https, nginx-ingress

I was trying to make end-to-end encryption (HTTPs request) work and I was able to make the connection secure all the way to the pod using the following annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

I'm still trying to figure out how request is re-encrypted between my ingress and my service:

```
client -- (HTTPS) --> Ingress controller (TLS Termination) -- (HTTPS) --> Service ----> Pod
```

In addition, is adding the above annotation to ingress is enough to ensure ingress will make new connection against my service in HTTPs ?

My .NET core app requires certificate when listening on 443 port I need to supply a certificate so I'm trying to understand which certificate should be used between ingress and my app - currently loaded just a random cert into my app and its working so I'm not sure what is the purpose of the cert

Another Approach I tried:
I created a secret named myCert in my k8s cluster and also loaded the same cert into my .net core app.
added the following annotations to ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name: cert-subject-alternative-nameplaceholder.com
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-secret: myCert
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-server-name: 'on'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify: 'on'
```

Now when I make an HTTPS request I get:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx</center>
</body>
```

trying to figure out if Backend Certificate Authentication with nginx-ingress, thats what Im looking for, not sure why Im getting 503...

thanks

Comment: Why not terminate the TLS in nginx ingress and save the trouble with having to deal with certificate in the service itself?

Comment: One of the requirements in our project is to have a a secured HTTPS request all the way, so running it to my application as HTTP isn't applicable.

Comment: This error could be because of the proxy-ssl-secret annotation. The secret name must be defined in the format "namespace/secretName". See: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-certificate-authentication for details.